# My Lantern cloud server has a domain name that looks like typo-squatting, should I be worried?

Tags: typosquatting

[Lantern](https://getlantern.org/) is an app to avoid censorship. It is hosted at `getlantern.org`.

I just noticed that the cloud server my client is using is actually `roundrobin.getiantern.org`

[image: Lantern getlantern roundrobin.getiantem.org]

Notice the `i` in `getiantern` instead of `getlantern`.
They look extremely similar with the app's font, I had to look very closely to see the difference.

Should I be worried?
Or can the `getiantern` domain be trusted?

`getiantern` is [not found in the Lantern source code](https://github.com/getlantern/lantern/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=getiantern).

Comment: The [whois info of `getiantern.org`](http://whois.domaintools.com/getiantern.org) says that it is registred via Domains By Proxy, which means that the registrant wants to hide their identity. This is no proof that they have a malicious intent, but doesn't look trustworthy either.

Comment: If we look at the Whois info again it shows that it was registered on October 13, 2013 and expires on October 13, 2018 a person who plans on putting it up on Sedo.com will not register it for that long. Maybe someone plans on doing some phishing attacks.

Comment: But given the fact that `getlantern.org` itself is also registered over Domains By Proxy it could be part of the real Latern program. I don't think it is unnormal for a tool like this, perhaps the creator of it needs some anonymity to prevent legal consequences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities in my mind:

Given the fact that you state that the apps font is very little, could it be that `roundrobin.getiantern.org` is in fact `roundrobin.getiantem.org`? Notice that the only difference is `rn` and `m` at the end of the domain name, and with some fonts it may be difficult to read especially if you have the domain getlatern in mind.

Why am I asking this? The domain `roundrobin.getiantem.org` is [mentioned in the source](https://github.com/getlantern/lantern/blob/1031861663bdc527fd0df070ed2adfa0b07298e4/src/main/java/org/lantern/S3Config.java) (line 63).

The second option is found in the same code file on lines 33-43:

```
final File cfcerts = new File("cloudflare-certs");
final File[] certs = cfcerts.listFiles();
for (final File cert : certs) {
    LOG.info("Loading cert...{}", cert);
    try {
        DEFAULT_HOSTS_TO_CERTS.put(cert.getName(), 
                Files.toString(cert, Charsets.UTF_8).trim());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.error("Could not load cert?", e);
    }
}
```

What it does is looking in a folder named `cloudflare-certs` and loading all hosts for the certificates in that folder. It may be that there is a certificate for `roundrobin.getiantern.org`. But if so you should be carefull in the git repository there is no such certificate.

As far as I could see with a quick view, Latern tries to take an host from a certificate and connects to `roundrobin.getiantem.org` if this fails.

If none of the two options apply you should perhaps really be worried as someone may try to manipulate your traffic. Or you may accidentally downloaded a malicious package with different servers.

Comment: You're right, it is actually `getiantem`!

Comment: Well in this case I think we have an answer to your question, and you don't have to be worried.